# Skip NOT Available values while scraping JSON response

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a bunch of URLs that I want to scrape. Some links have values that don't exist in others. I wanted to know how can I avoid getting an error if there is no value in any URL?

I tried the `try` and `except` but it didn't work

In this [link](https://www.cbr.nl/web/show?id=289168&langid=43&channel=json&cachetimeout=-1&elementHolder=289170&ssiObjectClassName=nl.gx.webmanager.cms.layout.PagePart&ssiObjectId=285674&contentid=3780&examtype=B), you will see 4 values under examInformation. I wrote the expression for 5 values and it gives me an error. I want it to just skip if the value doesn't exist.

Here is my code:

```
    try:
        location_1 = schools['examInformation'][0]['cbrLocationShortName']
    except:
        pass
    try:
        location_2 = schools['examInformation'][1]['cbrLocationShortName']
    except:
        pass
    try:
        location_3 = schools['examInformation'][2]['cbrLocationShortName']
    except:
        pass
    try:
        location_4 = schools['examInformation'][3]['cbrLocationShortName']
    except:
        pass
    try:
        location_5 = schools['examInformation'][4]['cbrLocationShortName']
    except:
        pass

   yield {
       "Location 1": location_1 if location_1 else "N/A",
       "Location 2": location_2 if location_2 else "N/A",
       "Location 3": location_3 if location_3 else "N/A",
       "Location 4": location_4 if location_4 else "N/A",
       "Location 5": location_5 if location_5 else "N/A",    
   }
```

I am getting the following error:

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'location_5' referenced before assignment**

> NOTE: I am using scrapy with JSON library

Comment: CodeWithAwais I deleted my answer, as I was too quick to assume what the error was. I suggest you go with @Madjazz loop solution, it's a better design than the repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix would be to assign a None or your final 'N/A' value to each variable in the except block, i.e:

```py
 try:
     location_5 = schools['examInformation'][4]['cbrLocationShortName']
 except:
     location_5 = 'N/A'

    yield {
           "Location 5": location_5,   
    }
```

If you want to avoid all the code duplication and exception handling in your example, I would pack it into a loop with a safe get method:

```py
locations = {}
exam_information = schools['examInformation']

for i in range(len(exam_information)):
    location_key = f'Location {i + 1}'
    locations[location_key] = exam_information[i].get('cbrLocationShortName', 'N/A')

yield locations
```